# Extend registration form in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to extend Sylius 'CustomerRegistrationType' as 'CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension' and added few new fields and removed some fields.

I have added `countrycode` in `CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension` file

```
`$builder->add('dob', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'sylius.form.customer.phone_number',
            ]);`
```

And my service.yml contains

```
services:
    app.form.extension.type.customer_registration:
        class: adf\Form\Extension\Customer\CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Customer\CustomerRegistrationType }
```

But I'm getting error like :

```
Neither the property "dob" nor one of the methods "getDob()", "dob()", "isDob()", "hasDob()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer".
```

It is referring to `Customer` Model. Where do I need to override Model or how can I pass entity `SyliusShopUser` which is extended from `use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser`

In `SyliusShopUser` we have created `dob` field:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dob", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dob;

/**
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
public function getDob()
{
    return $this->dob;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime|null $dob
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function setDob($dob)
{
    $this->dob = $dob;

    return $this;
}
```